# .net 7 convert object to correct type when deserialising request

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

It is possible to convert object value to correct type in .net 7 web application when data is deserializing in controller? In DB I have table with sql_variant, so DTO have object property:

`public object Value {get; set;}`

When I send json to controller (argument is [FromBody]), I have in value: Value kind = string: "text", so before saving with EF Core I need convert value to string, because if I don't do this I have error like: "No mapping exists from object type System.Text.Json.JsonElement to a known managed provider native type."

Comment: Why are you using `sql_variant`? That's the root of the problem. That type is essentially a legacy type everybody in the SQL Server team would like to forget about. It was added to make using **simple** OLE values easier, mainly for VB6 applications and making migration from Access easier. It was not meant to store complex values, that's what the `xml` type was for. Nowadays, a string field containing JSON is as fast as using an indexed XML field.

Comment: Storing an entire form's data as a single `sql_variant` is definitely a bad idea. If you convert it to a string, you really need a `nvarchar` column, not a `sql_variant`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the database is quite old and that's how it was designed, I'm not able to change it. Depending on the data, sql_variant stores string, int, long, real, datetime data. I have to live with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you must use `sql_variant` and are stuck with an `object` type for your `Value`, a [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) `JsonConverter` is what you might need:

Decorate your Dto's property:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyValueJsonConverter))]
public object Value {get; set;}
```

And override `JsonConverter`:

```
public class MyValueJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            reader.GetString()!;

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        string stringValue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(stringValue);
}
```